# Not redirected to SSL/acme.json empty

Tags: docker, traefik

I am using traefik as reverse proxy for cryptpad. Traefik is running in a docker container. I used this docs to solve this issue: https://github.com/xwiki-labs/cryptpad/wiki/Docker-(with-Nginx-and-Traefik)#configuring-traefik

That's what I did:

```
$ mkdir traefik && cd traefik
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/traefik.sample.toml
$ mv traefik.sample.toml traefik.toml
$ touch acme.json && chmod 600 acme.json
```

I added this to `traefik.toml`:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[acme]
email = "me@example.org"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Created `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - proxy
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

And created/started traefik with docker-compose up -dll .

Well - for http it works fine so far - but I am not being redirected to https. And if I would, the connection would be reset (https://cryptpad.mydomain.org -> connection refused).

I checked if something is listening for http/https:

```
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                           :::http                                        :::*                    
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                           :::https                                       :::*
```

And tried to telnet it:

```
[root@cryptpad ~]# telnet localhost 443
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What did I miss?